# Finding relationship records for which there is no reverse relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

In my Rails application I have a `relationships` table with 2 columns `origin_id` and `target_id`. I need to build a scope `without_reverse_relationship` that returns all the relationships for which there is no reverse relationship.

For instance if I have the following `relationships` records:

```
origin_id target_id 
     1          2
     2          1
     1          3
```

I'd like that `Relationship.without_reverse_relationship` returns only the last record (origin_id = 1, target_id = 3), because the reverse record (origin_id = 3, target_id = 1) does not exist in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM relationships r1
  LEFT JOIN relationships r2
    ON r2.origin_id = r1.target_id
      AND r2.target_id = r1.origin_id
WHERE r2.origin_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of logic should work.  The syntax will depend on your rdbms, which you did not specify.

```
 select *
 from relationships
 where concat(to_string(originId), to_string(target_id)) in
 (select concat(to_string(originId), to_string(target_id))
 from relationships
 except 
 select concat(to_string(target_id), _string(originId))
 from relationships)
```